# I can't resolve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException despite already submitted solutions

Tags: java

I have a program which effectively takes a name (eg. "John Doe") and 'festifies' it, replacing the name with a more festive name depending on the first letter of the name.

My program is throwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Elves.compareInput(Elves.java:38)
        at Elves.start(Elves.java:56)
        at Elves.main(Elves.java:63)
```

Which I can't quite seem to figure out! I understand it's doing this because my for loop is exceeding the bounds of my array, but I can't figure out how to resolve it, nor do I understand why it won't work as it should, because I think my code is correct.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Elves
{
    String[] festiveFirstNames = {"Peppermint","Jazzy","Peppy","Snowball","Fritz","Jingles","Bixby","Cosmo","Oodles","Zippy","Cocoa","Scout","Snickerdoodle","Buddy","Bitsy","Chippey","Pipsie","Lucky","Sugar","Chipper","Fisbee","Marshmallow","Elwood","Star","Snowflake","Twinkle"};
    String[] festiveLastNames = new String[27];
    char[] alphabetLetters = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    public void takeInput() // Method to take user input for first and second name and pass into 'compareInput' method
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        char firstNameChar;
        char lastNameChar;

        //error checking System.out.println(festiveFirstNames.length);
        //error checking System.out.println(alphabetLetters.length);
        System.out.print("Enter the first name: ");
        firstName = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase(); // Takes user input, capitalises and inserts into 'firstName' string
        firstNameChar = firstName.charAt(0); // Takes the first letter of the input and inserts into 'firstNameChar'

        System.out.print("Enter the last name: ");
        lastName = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase(); // Takes user input, capitalises and inserts into 'lastName' string
        lastNameChar = lastName.charAt(0); // Takes the first letter of the input and inserts into 'lastNameChar'

        //error checking System.out.println(firstNameChar + "\n" + lastNameChar);

        compareInput(firstNameChar, lastNameChar); // Passes two characters into the 'compareInput' method
    }

    public void compareInput(char ... nameInput)
    {
        String newFirstName = "";
        String newLastName = "";

        for (int i=0; i<alphabetLetters.length-1; i++) // Loops while 'i' less than length of alphabetLetters-1
        {
            if (alphabetLetters[i] == nameInput[0]) // If alphabet at position 'i' equals 'nameInput[0]' AKA 'firstNameChar'
            {
                newFirstName = festiveFirstNames[i]; // Update 'newFirstName' with position 'i' from 'festiveFirstNames'
            }
            //System.out.println(i);
        }

        produceOutput(newFirstName, newLastName);
    }

    public void produceOutput(String ... newNames)
    {
        System.out.println("New first name is " + newNames[0]);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        takeInput();
        compareInput();
        produceOutput();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Elves e = new Elves();
        e.start();
    }
}
```

The error occurs within my 'compareInput' method, specifically the 'if' statement.

Comment: You have an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `nameInput[0]`, not `alphabetLetters[i]`:

```
public void start()
{
    takeInput();
    compareInput(); // <-- Here, you call compareInput with an EMPTY array nameInput
    produceOutput();
}
```

...

```
public void compareInput(char ... nameInput)
{
    ...

        // Here, nameInput[0] will produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
        // since the nameInput array is empty: 
        if (alphabetLetters[i] == nameInput[0]) 
    ...
```

Comment: Oh! I understand now, it's because I was calling the 'compareInput' and 'produceOutput' methods within my 'start' method even though I'd already called them within their parent methods. Thank you for pointing this blatantly obvious flaw out to me.

I must ask, though perhaps somewhat unrelated, how would I pass those variables without running the method? Is that possible?

Comment: In your program, `takeInput()` calls `compareInput()` which in turn calls `produceOutput()`. So you could just call only `takeInput()` in the `start()` method. 
Alternatively, you could "pass the values" between the methods by storing them in private fields, or by using return values, like this (pseudocode): `var inputs = takeInput(); var compareResult = compareInput(inputs); produceOutput(compareResult);`